# Where is Domino Designer Java agent template stored?

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I wonder where the code that's getting generated by Domino Designer is stored when creating a new JavaAgent gets is *template*?

```
import lotus.domino.*;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {

      try {
          Session session = getSession();
          AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();

          // (Your code goes here)

      } catch(Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

I was thinking of tweaking it to our *corporate standards* if editable…

Answer (score 0):

These code templates are controlled in Preferencs/Java/Code Style/Code Templates. The actual location is going to be squirrelled away in your /workspace.

You can import and export the code templates there. I would simply put your standard template somewhere on a file server and tell developers to import it. It's theoretically possible to do this some more elegant way, but it's probably flaky because one is not guaranteed that the files will always be saved in the same place.

Comment: Are we talking about the same thing here? As you say, code templates are maintained under Preferences, but the code sample I sent here isn't there. This one comes directly from Designer when creating a Java agent.

Comment: Ahhh - I see what you mean, you mean the tiny Agent stub which gets created when one makes a new Java Agent. In that case, I don't know. I wouldn't be surprised if this is hardcoded.

Comment: Exactly, it's inherited from older Designer version but it would be nice to know if possible. Thx